# Stock market module or configuration?

Tags: commerce

I am researching a project and am interested in learning if there is a way or module to configure Drupal Commerce to act essentially as a stock exchange.  Where multiple sellers would be able to post prices for a limited number of products (like ticker symbols on an exchange) and buyers would be able to purchase X number of said products, which would be filled from lowest to highest price?

If there is not such a configuration and/or module that implements this functionality, how complicated would it be to develop one for the Drupal Commerce stack?

The purpose of this is to trade units of quota allocation (think carbon offset trading or commodities trading) so there is no physical delivery necessary.  Just a limited number of quota types, seller's prices, and purchaser orders that would be filled from low to high.

Amazon has a similar feature where multiple merchants sell the same product on the Amazon Marketplace.  I am looking to implement something like that.

If Drupal Commerce is not the best platform to build this project, if someone has any idea/or experience with something similar, I'd appreciate the advice.

Answer (score 0):

I think you would have to write your own inventory system as this is not the kind of use-case Commerce is usually used for.

[Commerce does have a number of hooks](http://api.drupalcommerce.org/) you can use to control the cart and checkout, but I'm pretty sure that user-ownership of [stock](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_stock) is not something that has been tackled successfully, yet.